# IE won't make image equal page height

Tags: html, internet-explorer, height

I have done a lot of research trying to solve this issue, and I cannot find a solution. I'm hoping someone here can provide some insight.

The site:  www.lifelinepilots.org/new_site/Home.html

The problem: In Internet Explorer, the sidebar images won't expand to equal the varying page height throughout the site. I have set the image height to 100%, and the body height to 100%. The bar stretches to equal the page height with no issues in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome, but not in Explorer. What could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### First Method

Make the height of **Home_Page2_01.png** and **Home_Page2_05.png** twice the size.

### Alternative method

Add the following styles to td cells of those images.

```
<td rowspan="25" align="left" valign="center" 
   style="background: url("images/Home_Page2_01.png") top left repeat-y;">
   <img src="images/Home_Page2_01.png"  alt="" width="32" height="100%" id="sidebar">
</td>

...

<td rowspan="25" align="left" valign="top" 
   style="background: url("images/Home_Page2_05.png") top left repeat-y;"
   <img src="images/Home_Page2_05.png" width="30" height="100%" alt=""></td>
<td>
```